# Is there a good tag to refer to political points of view held by a specific side of a debate?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is two-part:

1) What is a good META.politics.SE tag to use on questions which deal with content that can be described as "points of view from one side of political debate"? E.g. "what do the conservative thinkers say on the topic of 'X'"?

2) What is a good tag for the main site (either the same tag or different one) to label questions which deal with "points of view from one side of political debate"?

Please note that I'm not asking about relative quality or welcomeness of discussing such things in posts, merely a good tag to label them once they are asked.

Comment: What is the need for this tag?  is it an actual need for an existing question or that you perceive as being needed at some point?

Comment: @Chad - Mostly for the future, but I'm pretty sure I can find some questions where such a tag would be applicable now. My main example of an existing question would be my last META one before this one.

Comment: Talking Point??

Comment: As a good example, here is a question that fits the purpose I had in mind: [How does libertarianism challenge a “property is theft” counter-argument to a “tax is theft” argument?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-does-libertarianism-challenge-a-property-is-theft-counter-argument-to-a-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially "justification" might be a good way of asking "What is party X's justification for position Y."

Answer (score 1):

[talking-points](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talking-points) - These topics are often called talking points as they are approved messages that the party and the office wishes to see put out.

Comment: Hm. I like this one, but doesn't it have connotation that the question is asked "from the point of view of talking-point side"? Which is contrary to what I intend as usage.

Comment: @DVK - Talking points are always from the talker's side.  They are approved messages and often the word choice is emphasized like to avoid calling bengahzi a terrorist attack or to explain how writing of the 47% is a good thing.

Comment: Right, that's my point... this tag is intended to ask questions ABOUT talking points, often from the OPPOSITE side from the talker. "Why is this talking point logical/accurate"?

Comment: I think the question about a talking point should be objective and not from a side.

Comment: yes. But usually people agreeing with talking points won't ask questions about them.

Comment: The question will be about the talking point hopefully asking an objective question about it.  Possibly for clarification as many of the talking points are intentionally obtuse or obfuscating the facts.

Comment: see the this example. Objective, but asked from opposition point of view. http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-does-libertarianism-challenge-a-property-is-theft-counter-argument-to-a-t

Comment: @DVK - I dislike that Question I think it is begging for a discussion.  So it is not really constructive by SE terms.  I think it could work if asked if any experts have addressed that conundrum.  But the political view point of libertarianism is does not have to defend it self or counter anything.  It is those who hold libertarian beliefs that feel the need to counter the arguments which is why i say it is asking for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [one-sided](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-sided)?

Actually, the first to come to mind was [partisan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partisan), but that's problematic because

1. It also refers to a number of WW2 resistance groups
2. In the US, I get the impression it's used to refer specifically to political parties.

Comment: 3. I always misspell it as [partizan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FK_Partizan).

Answer (score -1):

My own proposal - which I personally am ***not*** satisfied with - is [political-side](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-side)